# Can anyone explain to me what "another draft was linked but was not submitted" means?

Tags: support, documentation

I'm trying to make some changes to a topic in documentation, now I've not really kept up with this project so I'm not an expert user... When I submit my (admittedly minor changes) It keeps telling me:

[image]

and I have no idea what this means?

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Shouldn't this be a bit more intuitive?

In case it matters I was attempting to edit [this doc on the Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/selenium-webdriver/878/introduction-to-selenium-webdriver/2963/installation-or-setup#t=201609211456013162525)

Comment: Did you move some examples out or in?

Comment: No, I altered the title and deleted an extra bullet point that was in the bottom with no text. It was **very** minor, not sure if that made any difference

Comment: Do you possibly have another draft on this topic?

Comment: Not that I am aware of? Still happening...FYI?